# Excel VBA filtering data without deleting blanks

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have a question regarding filtering text in columns in Excel / VBA. Here is my starting point (can't post images):

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | bla | bla |
| empty | bla | bla |
| value2 | bla | bla |
| value1 | bla | bla |
| empty ​ | bla | bla |
| value2 | bla | bla |

What I want to do is to use a text filter on the "Column1" for "value1" so that the result includes the lines with the "empty" value in column1. The filtering result should look like that:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | bla | bla |
| empty | bla | bla |
| value1 | bla | bla |
| empty ​ | bla | bla |

However, when I use a normal text filter in Excel on column1 for "value1" I get this result, without the lines that have "empty" in Column1:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | bla | bla |
| value1 | bla | bla |

What I lack is a general idea of how this could be done in Excel / VBA. Somehow the lines with empty should be "connected" to those with "value1" in kind of of a range?
Any suggestions very much appreciated!!

Comment: Filter has a "blanks" option: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxQsE.png

Comment: @BigBen yes, thank you. However, this gives me all blanks, but I want only the blanks under the "good" values (in example above value1) and not those under the value2. So it should be kind of conditional...

Answer (score 1):

Use the Macro Recorder and then some cleanup:

```
Sub Macro1()
    With Range("A1:C7")
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=value1", _
            Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the response - I think I am half way there. As far as I understand it will this bring me all the blanks in the table. However, I would like to get only those blanks that stand under a "good value" (value1) and NOT those under value2. So it should be kind of conditional... Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the same Filter with VBA that you can set using the Filter in Excel. Using the Macro-Recorder reveals the syntax.

Assuming that you want to filter data in Columns A to C, you can use

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$C").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=value1", _ 
    Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
```

As you can see, the search for blank is done using the filter criteria `"="`

If you want to see all values for more than one value *plus* blanks, use

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$C").AutoFilter Field:=1, _
      Criteria1:=Array("value1", "value2", "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

you put all values that you want to see into an Array, and that Array is passed as parameter to the Criteria1. Again, blank is represented by `"="`.

**Update**
If you want to use Autofilter to show all rows that either have a specific value *or* blank *and* the previous row has this value, you can solve this with a helper column. Assuming your criteria is in column A, put a formula in the helper column: `=IF(A2="",A1,A2)` and filter on this column.

If you don't want a helper column, you will need to write a VBA routine that checks row by row if to show or hide this row.

Comment: Thank you for the response - I think I am half way there. As far as I understand it, this will bring me all the blanks in the table. However, I would like to get only those blanks that stand under a "good value" (value1) and NOT those under value2. So it should be kind of conditional... Is that possible?